# Inner divs in one line. inner left is dynamic

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="container"><div id="textOnLeft">{{someDynamicText}}</div><div id="btnOnRight"><button></button></div></div>
```

The button should be always to the right of the dynamic text.
Case the width of the text + width of the button are over the width of the container - the text should be ellipsis.

Please you guidance.

Thanks,
Ampo.

Comment: The width of the container is also dynamic to support responsiveness.

Comment: Where is your current css? What width do you want the container to be? You gave us nothing to work with.

Comment: All of this is in popup.  the initial width is 500px - but can be resized (max-width: 800px, min-width: 300px)

Comment: What CSS have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not going to get an ellipsis unless you set a certain width limit on `textOnLeft`. The rest is the magic of `flexbox`.

```css
#container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="textOnLeft">{{someDynamicText}}</div>
  <div id="btnOnRight">
    <button></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've the solution. Here you're the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My first Backbone app</title>
    <style>
        #container { display: flex; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
       <div id="textOnLeft">{{someDynamicText}}</div>
       <button>button</button>
    </div>
    <script>
       window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
          var text = "{{someDynamicText}}";
          var textField = document.getElementById("textOnLeft");
          if (window.innerWidth < 500) {
             textField.innerHTML = "...";
          }
          else {
             textField.innerHTML = text;
          }
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I choose 500px only for this example, you can choose whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks, but preferable with no JQuery.   HTML+CSS

Comment: I just rewrote my code using pure, vanilla JavaScript